# Get item index when using filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I'm using this code to get items that match a particular keyword.

```
var match_data = function(search_str, items) {
    var reg = new RegExp(search_str.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
    return items.filter(function(item_data) {
        if (item_data.match(reg)) {
            return item_data;
        }
    });
};
```

Is there any way I can get the index of the matched item as well ?

Also I keep getting this warning when my search string comtains `\` anywhere in it:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /iw*m\w*\/: \ at end of pattern(…)`

Can you guys please help me solve this error as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result.

Comment: filter expect a boolean value, not the value of the item, if it should be inserted into the result set.

Comment: About index: you can use `indexOf(val)` function to get the index of value from the array.

Comment: @rakaz, this method won't work if you have 2 items with the exact same text in the list ( eg. var list = [ 'abc', 'def', 'abc', 'efg' ] )

Answer (score 2):

You could use another array and the index from the callback API of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var match_data = function(search_str, items) {
        var reg = new RegExp(search_str.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i'),
            indices = [];

        return {
            result: items.filter(function(item_data, index) {
                if (item_data.match(reg)) {
                    indices.push(index);
                    return true;
                }
            }),
            indices: indices
        };
    };
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'll give this a try and let you know